# Where to declare 3rd Party Libs used in AppExchange packages

Tags: appexchange, isv, licenses, open-source

In my commercial Managed Packages on the AppExchange, I am planning to use a bunch of BSD-3 and MIT-licenced Open Source libraries like:

- https://github.com/apexfarm/ApexTriggerHandler/blob/master/LICENSE
- https://github.com/beyond-the-cloud-dev/soql-lib/blob/main/LICENSE

I now want to understand what is legally required to use them correctly:

1. Do I need to declare their usage publically,
2. link their licenses or repos
3. Do I do this on the AppExchange listing, in one of the publicly available docs, or on a page in the app like shown here [image]

Comment: I'm no lawyer, but the legal requirements depend on the demands of the individual licenses themselves. For example, the MIT license only requires the source code to continue to contain the copyright notice. There is no need for anything else. Having a "credit where credit is due" list of the packages even with MIT licenses is a nice-to-do (though, of course, could be used by bad actors to help identify software to target using known vulnerabilities).